# how use secrets in .yaml file in ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets, ingress-nginx

I create my secret in my cluster using this command

```
kubectl create secret tls server --key server.key --cert server.crt
```

I am using ingress-nginx for my deployment file and I want to use above secrete in .yaml file.
Anyone know how can I use this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: alpha-ingress-srv
   annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
     # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-certificate: "fake-ssl-cert"
     # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-certificate-key: "fake-ssl-cert"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-certificate: "server"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-certificate-key: "server.key"
spec:
   rules:
     - host: kavishkamk.live
       http:
          paths:
           - path: /api/users/?(.*)
             pathType: Prefix
             backend:
               service:
                 name: alpha-auth-srv
                 port:
                    number: 4000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `tls` field to your spec:

```
spec:
   tls:
   - hosts:
       - kavishkamk.live
     secretName: server   
   rules:
     - host: kavishkamk.live
       http:
          paths:
           - path: /api/users/?(.*)
             pathType: Prefix
             backend:
               service:
                 name: alpha-auth-srv
                 port:
                    number: 4000
```